# Mysql Join vs Select inside Select

Tags: mysql

I am making some tracking system for my iOS & Android apps. My mysql server restarts when it has really big queries (I don't know how many exactly). So I was thinking in the performance.

I don't know if it helps but my server can handle more than 500 statements per minute

My question is: Its faster to make Two selected (or more) in the same statement or make a join?

DB: I have two tables, one with the devices that people connect and another table with the apps that  connect to my apps.

EDIT: My db it's on InnoDB, with primary & auto-increment index to ID. and FK to deviceID & appID

So when the user login, I need to check if he is register in the serve.
(I am using SELECT * from testing proposes)

Two select statements

```
SELECT * FROM devicesApps WHERE appID='$idApp' and 
deviceID IN (SELECT id FROM devices WHERE fingerprint='$fingerprint')
```

Join

```
SELECT * FROM devicesApps da, devices d WHERE da.appID='$idApp' 
and da.deviceID=d.id and d.fingerprint='$fingerprint'
```

Which is faster or both are the same? I need only 1 row.

Thanks

Comment: I'll bet 2. is faster..

Comment: I defy @Tmckeown to devise a scenario in which 1 is faster!

Answer (score 0):

It always depend on multiple factors like index seeks, scans.  Your answer will become more clear if you have execution plans to compare.

Comment: My db it's on InnoDB, with primary & auto-increment index to ID. and FK to deviceID & appID

Comment: FK's don't mean indexed, they are just constraints.  You should use EXPLAIN to see the plan.  But if your PK is the ID and you have considerable amount of data then that would be your best option most likely.

Answer (score 0):

For older versions of MySQL, `in` with a subquery was suboptimal  I believe the problem has been fixed in the most recent version.

The version with the `join` should be written using explicit join syntax.  This doesn't affect performance, but it is the preferred SQL syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM devicesApps da join
     devices d
     on da.deviceID = d.id
WHERE da.appID = '$idApp' and d.fingerprint = '$fingerprint';
```

Note, by the way, that the two versions of the query do *not* do the same thing.  If there are multiple devices that match, then the first returns one row per device app and the second will return one row per device.

You can speed both queries with additional indexes, such as `device(fingerprint, id)` and `devicesApps(appId, deviceId)`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, About the second one, I make it really fast but i mean to return the same things :S. But which one do you said (supposing that return the same) would be faster?

Comment: @EduardoIglesias . . . I would go with the second one, because its performance is version-independent.